# Redirect curl to while loop

Tags: linux, bash, curl

Is there any way to redirect the curl output to a while loop?

```
while read l; do 
  echo 123 $l; 
done < curl 'URL'
```

Or is there a better way to do this?  I simply need to read the contents of a page and prepend something to each line and save it to a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to redirect the output of curl using **process substitution** as follows:

```
while read -r l; do 
    echo "123 $l"
done < <(curl 'URL')
```

You can also use the output of a quoted **command substitution** and a **herestring** as follows:

```
while read -r l; do 
    echo "123 $l"
done <<<"$(curl 'URL')"
```

(though **process substitution** is preferred)

**note:** for redirecting to a file, you can redirect the output of a block, rather than a line at a time:

```
:>outfile    ## truncate outfile if it exists
{
    while read -r l; do 
        echo "123 $l"
    done < <(curl 'URL') 
}>outfile
```

Comment: Very nice.  Is the -r to protect against some kind of injection attack?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pipe operator `|`

```
curl 'URL' | while read l; do 
   echo 123 $l >> file.txt
done
```

Comment: You do not need a **pipe** and in fact, you should avoid using a pipe to feed a read loop. Use process substitution.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm willing to accept I'm wrong but it'd be nice if you said why i.e why you shouldn't use a pipe to feed a read loop.

Comment: Well I'm not saying your wrong, you can use a `pipe`, but just like anytime you think `cat file | ...`, you have just committed a **UUOC** (unnecessary use of `cat`). **Redirection** is the proper way to provide input/output from one process to another, unless you have more than 2. Then you must use pipes. Secondly, every pipe spawns an additional subshell that is unneeded in almost all cases.

Comment: Makes sense when you put it in terms of cat. Thanks.